# Querying a collection with mongoid and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I want to query many different collections from a model in rails.

For example:

```
class Statistics
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

I want to be able to query a statistics or maybe a my_stats collection.  Is that possible?  How can I do it?

Comment: What's the actual question or problem? The docs for mongoid are decent - http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/finders.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear. If you want to know how to define your own collection name, instead of having Mongoid auto-generate one via the class name/ActiveSupport, you can do that using the `store_in` method. Like so:

```
class Statistics
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in :mystats
end
```

If you're asking how to search multiple collections with one query, that isn't possible in MongoDB, as far as I'm aware.